# Show DIV(s) corresponding to the link clicked and show( ) all DIV(s) when "view all" link is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, click

here is the html

```
<div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu">
    <li><a href="#" data-page="showall">View All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-page="page1">Antigua</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-page="page2">Barbados</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-page="page3">Tortola, BVI</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#" data-page="page4">The Grenadines</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#" data-page="page5">St. Lucia</a></li> 
  </ul>
</div>
```

and here is the script

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready( function() {

var curPage="";

   $("#menu a").click(function() {
     $(".content").hide();

        if (curPage.length) { 
            $("#"+curPage).hide();
        }
        curPage=$(this).data("page");
        $("#"+curPage).fadeIn(1000);
    });

 });
</script>
```

I need help with the "View All" link. The nav filters what I want to view separately but I would like to display all div(s) as well when I click the "view all" link.

Comment: please post the `.content` elements too, delete their content just leave the containers so we can see the structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following code in your js,

```
if(curPage=='showall')
    $(".content").fadeIn(1000);
```

and this will show all `content` class divs.

Check the following code snippet.

```js
$(document).ready( function() {

var curPage="";

   $("#menu a").click(function() {
     $(".content").hide();

        if (curPage.length) { 
            $("#"+curPage).hide();
        }
        curPage=$(this).data("page");
        $("#"+curPage).fadeIn(1000);
  if(curPage=='showall')
   $(".content").fadeIn(1000);
    });

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu">
    <li><a href="#" data-page="showall">View All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-page="page1">Antigua</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-page="page2">Barbados</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="content" id="page1">
Hello
</div>
<div class="content" id="page2">
World
</div>
```

Comment: @sophyweb you are welcome! If you think it solved your problem, pls accept the answer. :)

Comment: Sorry.. just figured it out. I am new. :)  Thanks again.